# Convert list of object with array to and from json file

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to convert a list of 'Box' objects to a json file and also read it back in (json file to a list a 'Box' objects), but I'm a bit stuck on the implementation. I have written the below code, but I can only write a single 'Box' object to the json and convert a single 'Box' object back. When I try to do this with a list I hit errors like data that gets overwritten or just a single object that gets returned.

So in short, I want to write a List to json and convert json to List

I have the following data structure

Box model

```
class Box {
  final String nameBox;
  final List<Item> items;

  Box({@required this.nameBox, @required this.items});

  factory Box.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    var items = json['items'];
    List<Item> itemsList = items.cast<Item>();

    return new Box(
        nameBox: json["nameBox"],
        items: itemsList
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "nameBox": nameBox,
        "items": items,
      };
}

Box fromJson(String boxData) {
  return Box.fromJson(json.decode(boxData));
}

String toJson(Box box) {
  return json.encode(box.toJson());
}
```

Item model

```
class Item {
  final String itemName;
  final int quantity;

  Item({@required this.itemName, @required this.quantity});

  factory Item.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new Item(itemName: json["itemName"], quantity: json["quantity"]);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "itemName": itemName,
        "quantity": quantity,
      };
}

Item fromJson(String itemData) {
  return Item.fromJson(json.decode(itemData));
}

String toJson(Item item) {
  return json.encode(item.toJson());
}
```

writeToJson function

```
Future writeJson(Box box) async {
    final file = await _localFile;

    List<Box> tempRead = await returnBoxes();
    if (tempRead.isEmpty || tempRead == null) {
      return;
    }
    tempRead.add(box);
    file.writeAsString(json.encode(tempRead));
  }
```

readJson function

```
Future<List<Box>> returnBoxes() async {
    final file = await _localFile;

    List<Box> boxList = new List<Box>();

    Map<String, dynamic> content = await json.decode(file.readAsStringSync());

    boxList.add(Box.fromJson(content));

    return boxList;
  }
```

I also tried to cast the json content to a list, but then I hit some iterable errors. Any who can help me out?

Answer (score 1):

[JSON](https://www.json.org/) has this idiosyncrasy that everything is either an object or an array, and you don't know what you get until you decode it. Dart decodes the two json types into a `Map<String, dynamic>` and `List<dynamic>` respectively. (The reason that you get `dynamic` is because each of them could itself then be a value, a json array or a json object, recursively.)

Dart encodes a Dart object by calling `toJson` on it and a Dart list by emitting a `[` then each member of the list then a `]`.

Knowing that, it's easy to encode and decode arrays/lists. (I removed all the unnecessary code.)

```
class Box {
  final String nameBox;
  final List<Item> items;

  Box({@required this.nameBox, @required this.items});

  factory Box.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Box(
        nameBox: json['nameBox'],
        items: json['items'].map<Item>((e) => Item.fromJson(e)).toList(),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'nameBox': nameBox,
        'items': items,
      };
}

class Item {
  final String itemName;
  final int quantity;

  Item({@required this.itemName, @required this.quantity});

  factory Item.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Item(
        itemName: json['itemName'],
        quantity: json['quantity'],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'itemName': itemName,
        'quantity': quantity,
      };
}

Future writeJson(Box box) async {
  final file = await _localFile;

  var boxes = await returnBoxes();
  /* I think you probably don't want this...
  if (boxes.isEmpty || boxes == null) {
    return;
  }*/
  // but rather, this
  if (boxes == null) boxes = [];
  boxes.add(box);
  await file.writeAsString(json.encode(boxes));
}

Future<List<Box>> returnBoxes() async {
  final file = await _localFile;

  // because the json is an array (i.e. enclosed in []) it will be decoded
  // as a Dart List<dynamic>
  List<dynamic> d = json.decode(await file.readAsString());
  // here we map the List<dynamic> to a series of Box elements
  // each dynamic is passed to the Box.fromJson constructor
  // and the series is formed into a List by toList
  return d.map<Box>((e) => Box.fromJson(e)).toList();
}
```